# Convert Bootstrap 4 Tabs to select field

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I need to convert the Bootstrap 4 tab links to a sector field. Does someone know how to do this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav flex-column" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
 
 <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-a" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">1</a>
 
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-b" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">2</a>
 
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-c" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">3</a>

</div>


<div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-a" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">Creche Classes</h2>
 </div>
  
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-b" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">Troupe Competition Program</h2>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-c" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">Kinder Classes</h2>
</div>

<div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `sector field`?

Comment: I would like to be able to switch between the tabs using a select toggle.  Eaxmple: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select